# Shell script inside tmux window

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I saw a few of questions about that here but none of them worked to me and seems that did not worked for the people that was asking too...

SO, I want to execute a shell script in order to create a tmux window and execute another script inside this new window.

my script name is job_ex.sh and its content is

```
   #!/bin/bash
#

FF=1.29
SF=2.0
R_bg_gain=131.0
R_sm_gain=1.31
rho2=0.008
seed1=45789654


sample='jabulani'



cd 1
tmux new-session -s $sample
./simulaa $FF $SF $R_bg_gain $R_sm_gain $rho2 $seed1
```

however when I execute the shell "./job_ex.sh" it creates a tmux window and does nothing. If I detach the tmux window it executes the other script in the main window of my command line.

any suggestions?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86925/attach-to-tmux-session-and-run-a-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs your script inside a new tmux session and window

```
SESSION_NAME='jabulani'
ARGS=1.29
tmux new-session -s $SESSION_NAME "./simulaa $ARGS"
```